# PHP Loop through multi dimensional array but group by date and type and sum type?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am given an array of arrays, to simplify each array has

```
[0] => Array
(
[target_id]
[target_date]
[intensity_id]
[target_intensity] 
)
[1] => Array
(
[target_id]
[target_date]
[intensity_id]
[target_intensity] 
)
```

example data (the original array is an assoc array)

```
target_id target_date intensity_id target_intensity
1829    2017-06-23  2       good 
2013    2017-05-22  1       bad 
2024    2017-05-18  1       bad 
2029    2017-05-14  1       bad 
2032    2017-05-10  3       bad 
2329    2017-03-23  2       good 
2629    2017-03-12  3       excellent 
2830    2017-02-03  2       good 
3829    2017-02-23  2       good 
4029    2017-02-18  1       bad 
3829    2017-01-23  2       good 
3829    2016-12-12  3       excellent 
3829    2016-12-23  2       good
```

now i need to echo this data as input for a google stacked bar graph.

So I need to get the sum (number of times an intensity appears in a month) of target_intensity by month, like so

```
date        bad good    excellent
2016 dec     0  1   1
2017 jan    0   1   0
2017 feb    1   2   0
2017 mrt    0   1   1
2017 may    3   0   1
2017 jun    0   1   0
```

and here I am stuck

```
$tmpArray = array(
    array('target_id' => 1829, 'target_date' => '2017-06-23', 'intensity_id'=>2, 'target_intensity'=>'good'),
    array('target_id' => 2013, 'target_date' => '2017-05-22', 'intensity_id'=>1, 'target_intensity'=>'bad'),
    array('target_id' => 2024, 'target_date' => '2017-05-18', 'intensity_id'=>1, 'target_intensity'=>'bad'),
    array('target_id' => 2029, 'target_date' => '2017-05-14', 'intensity_id'=>1, 'target_intensity'=>'bad'),
    array('target_id' => 2032, 'target_date' => '2017-05-10', 'intensity_id'=>3, 'target_intensity'=>'bad'),
    array('target_id' => 2329, 'target_date' => '2017-03-23', 'intensity_id'=>2, 'target_intensity'=>'good'),
    array('target_id' => 2629, 'target_date' => '2017-03-12', 'intensity_id'=>3, 'target_intensity'=>'excellent'),
    array('target_id' => 2830, 'target_date' => '2017-02-03', 'intensity_id'=>2, 'target_intensity'=>'good'),
    array('target_id' => 3829, 'target_date' => '2017-02-23', 'intensity_id'=>2, 'target_intensity'=>'good'),
    array('target_id' => 4029, 'target_date' => '2017-02-18', 'intensity_id'=>1, 'target_intensity'=>'bad'),
    array('target_id' => 4039, 'target_date' => '2017-01-23', 'intensity_id'=>2, 'target_intensity'=>'good'),
    array('target_id' => 4049, 'target_date' => '2016-12-12', 'intensity_id'=>3, 'target_intensity'=>'excellent'),
    array('target_id' => 4056, 'target_date' => '2016-12-23', 'intensity_id'=>2, 'target_intensity'=>'good')
);

//echo $tmpArray[3]['target_date'];
//exit();
// should i first loop and order by month and then
//should i create 3 tmp arrays for bad, good and excellent


foreach ($tmpArray as $key => $values) {
    echo $values['target_date'] . '<br/>';
    //print_r ($values).'<br/>';
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
//        echo '<pre>';
        echo $key . ' - ' . $value . '<br/>';
//        echo '</pre>';
    }
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: year `2016` has only `excellent` and `good` intensity, so why did you specify `bad: 1` in your output for `2016 dec` ?

Comment: typo ..very sharp of you ....i am looking at this for quit awhile and i am making stupid mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you: Here I am just grouping the result to make the array

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array('target_id' => 1829, 'target_date' => '2017-06-23', 'intensity_id'=>2, 'target_intensity'=>'good'),
    array('target_id' => 2013, 'target_date' => '2017-05-22', 'intensity_id'=>1, 'target_intensity'=>'bad'),
    array('target_id' => 2024, 'target_date' => '2017-05-18', 'intensity_id'=>1, 'target_intensity'=>'bad'),
    array('target_id' => 2029, 'target_date' => '2017-05-14', 'intensity_id'=>1, 'target_intensity'=>'bad'),
    array('target_id' => 2032, 'target_date' => '2017-05-10', 'intensity_id'=>3, 'target_intensity'=>'bad'),
    array('target_id' => 2329, 'target_date' => '2017-03-23', 'intensity_id'=>2, 'target_intensity'=>'good'),
    array('target_id' => 2629, 'target_date' => '2017-03-12', 'intensity_id'=>3, 'target_intensity'=>'excellent'),
    array('target_id' => 2830, 'target_date' => '2017-02-03', 'intensity_id'=>2, 'target_intensity'=>'good'),
    array('target_id' => 3829, 'target_date' => '2017-02-23', 'intensity_id'=>2, 'target_intensity'=>'good'),
    array('target_id' => 4029, 'target_date' => '2017-02-18', 'intensity_id'=>1, 'target_intensity'=>'bad'),
    array('target_id' => 4039, 'target_date' => '2017-01-23', 'intensity_id'=>2, 'target_intensity'=>'good'),
    array('target_id' => 4049, 'target_date' => '2016-12-12', 'intensity_id'=>3, 'target_intensity'=>'excellent'),
    array('target_id' => 4056, 'target_date' => '2016-12-23', 'intensity_id'=>2, 'target_intensity'=>'good')
);

$output = [];
foreach($array as $value) {
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($value['target_date']));
    $month = date('M', strtotime($value['target_date']));

    if(empty($output[$year][$month]))
    $output[$year][$month] = ['bad' => 0, 'good' => 0, 'excellent' => 0];

    $output[$year][$month][$value['target_intensity']] += 1;
}

ksort($output);
ksort($output[$year]);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);

?>
```

Comment: `ksort($output[$year]);` ? So you only want to sort that last iterated subset?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two steps to be done, grouping the data by year/month and calculate the actual sum. In order to group you need a common identifier (just remove the day from your input). The sum is basically the grouping function.

```
$tmpArray = array_map(function($target) {
    $target['target_date'] = substr($target['target_date'], 0, 7);
    return $target;
}, $tmpArray);

$finalData = array_reduce($tmpArray, function($carry, $target) {
    if(!isset($carry[$target['target_date']])) {
        $carry[$target['target_date']] = ['bad' => 0, 'good' => 0, 'excellent' => 0];
    }
    $carry[$target['target_date']][$target['target_intensity']]++;
    return $carry;
}, []);
```